# Service Console Setup

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I'm setting up the service console in a second instance of Salesforce and I think there's something off in the configuration because the middle feed section doesn't look as expected.

[image]

The feed part of the console in our other org looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how to get this set up correctly?

Rochelle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is likely due to your page layout settings. If you edit the page layout being used and click 'Feed View' from the top, there's a setting called 'Enable Compact Feed View in the Console' which modifies the appearance of the feed. When it's turned on you get the colorful icons as you show in your bottom image.

[Help Document for reference](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212513&language=en_US)

[image: Select Feed View]

[image: Enable Compact Feed View]